# JavaFX 8: How to automatically input a file on start-up?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I’m using JavaFX 8 and JDK 1.8.0_77 in IntelliJ with SceneBuilder. I created a basic pixel editor app.  I have two windows(stages).  One is a 32x128 matrix of Circle Objects placed in a Grid Pane and the other is a Message Center in Main.

You can see the Message Center window at: https://virtualartsite.wordpress.com/message-center/

I want to save messages using the ***Message Center*** app and scroll them on an RGB LED matrix that’s also 32x128.  I save the messages in ***ArrayList<>*** of ***Message*** Objects and I write the ***ArrayList’s Message’s*** to a serialized file.  I write the file calling **writeObjArrayList ()** and input the file calling ***readObjArrayList().***

I am able to write and read the file successfully and **.add** all the ***Message*** objects to the ***ArrayList*** on start-up so the user can edit or delete any message from the ***viewMessages*** ComboBox.  BUT so far, I can only do so if I use a button event to call ***readObjArrayList()***.  This is the problem.

I want to read the file “behind the scenes”, when the app starts.  I want to automatically read the file when the program starts up; the user shouldn’t have to click on a button.

My best idea was to use the following code which compiles but doesn’t appear to execute any code:

```
    public void windowEvents(WindowEvent event){
    if(event.getSource() == viewMessages) readObjArrayList();
}
```

I thought a ***WindowEvent*** would be fired with ***windowEvents=#OnShow*** for the ComboBox, ***viewMessages(FX:ID)***.

Please advise.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/WindowEvent.html), the WindowEvent is related to *Window* showing/hiding actions. As Node classes aren't Windows, installing a WindowEvent handler on it won't have any effect.

Since you are using SceneBuilder, I assume that you must have an FXML file that has a `fx:controller` class defined. In any controller class, you can add a non-arg `initialize()` method which will be called right after the FXML file has been processed.

```
public class YourController {
    @FXML
    ComboBox viewMessages;

    public void initialize() {
        readObjArrayList();
    }

    private void readObjArrayList() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This most excellent solution worked the first time.  As a newbie to Java, the background FYI and code are very helpful now and in the future.  THANKS.

Comment: @sgroen Just to give a heads up, if an answer has helped you, acknowledge it by accepting the answer (click on the tick right beneath the vote-down). This will help the users in the future who stumble across the same problem.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Thanks for tip.